# Transit visa for connecting flights in the UK and Toronto

Tags: visas, transit-visas

Is a transit visa required when travelling from Abuja to the US via the UK and Toronto on Air Canada? I will have a 12-hour layover in the UK and 6 hours in Toronto.

Comment: A transit visa is required in Toronto unless you are a Canadian or USA citizen. The UK transit is a duplicate question, which I will link to.